# Use Notepad++ from Cygwin without having the shell wait for an exit code

Tags: bash, cygwin, notepad++

I'm running Cygwin and would like to use Notepad++ as the main shell editor, kind of like what I have on my Mac, where I can type `mate whatever` to open up an instance of TextMate. In my `~/.bashrc` file in Cygwin I have the following alias and environment variable set:

```
export EDITOR="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
alias np="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```

It mostly works: when I type `np whatever` or when a Cygwin program calls for $EDITOR, Notepad++ opens.

However, the shell waits until Notepad++ is closed and won't allow any input until then. This may be specific to bash, but how can I open Notepad++ from Cygwin and tell the shell to *not* wait for an exit code to continue? Adding a `&` to the end of the alias command doesn't work correctly—it just opens an untitled file and warns `filename: command not found` instead of opening the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try a `bash` function to pass the arguments before the ampersand:

```
np ()
{
    /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $* &
}
```

**BUT** the bigger issue may be the whole idea of *not* waiting until Notepad++ exits. Shell commands which use `$EDITOR` typically are *designed* to wait until the editor sends back an indication that the editing has completed. This usually means that the editor has exited (e.g. with `vi` or `nano`).

Emacs has a way to set your `EDITOR` to `emacsclient` and then when you're done editing, you hit a magical keystroke (`C-x #`) to indicate that editing is complete. If Notepad++ had something similar for cygwin users, I can see how this would work.

Another alternative is to use plain, boring, simple Notepad as your EDITOR and reserve Notepad++ for heavy use (I got the idea from [this blog post](http://blog.barrkel.com/2008/05/life-with-cygwin-paths-notepad-and.html))

Comment: Awesome—that worked. I'm going to go with the vanilla Notepad as EDITOR and Notepad++ as np()

Comment: Notepad also requires waiting for editing to be finished

Answer (score 8):

I solved it with a simple symlink.

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe ~/bin/npp
```

Of course ~/bin is in my $PATH.

Now to open a file I just type "npp filename.txt" from the cygwin prompt. I've haven't had to use the & at the end of the command.

This will also throw a tab into the currently running Notepad++ window rather than opening another one -- AND if the file is already open, it doesn't open it again.

Comment: How do you add ~/bin to $PATH?

Answer (score 3):

> export EDITOR="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ '(x86)'/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
>
> alias np="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ '(x86)'/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"

also works for x86

Answer (score 2):

Just add a space and an ampersand (&) to the end of your command and the shell will immediately return to input mode while leaving notepad++ open.

on edit:

I'm not talking about adding it to your alias.  Add it to the end of your command like this:

`np whatever &`

Comment: Ooh. This looks good so far. Is there a way to put that in the `.bash_profile` so I don't need to type it all the time?

Comment: I'm not a bash expert but I assume you could make your alias take a variable which is the argument, and also include the ampersand at the end.  Someone smarter with bash could probably give you the exact syntax.  I only knew how to answer your question because I used to do the exact same thing while working in a windows dev environment :)

Comment: You can't make an alias take a variable in Bash. You have to use a function or a script.

Answer (score 1):

Aliases don't take interpolated arguments. Use a function instead.

```
function np() { /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $1 & }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe $@ &
```

This script starts Notepad++ in the background, passing the command line arguments before the '&'

As [Doug advised](https://superuser.com/questions/168971/use-notepad-from-cygwin-without-having-the-shell-wait-for-an-exit-code/168990#168990), having a default `$EDITOR` that does not block may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific command in cygwin to accomplish this.   Make sure you download run.exe, and make sure it's in your PATH (or your PATH contains the executable)

```
alias np="run.exe /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"
```